# how FirebaseRecyclerAdapter get data from database realtime ? what is it using addValueEventListener or addListenerForSingleValueEvent...?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to get data from firebase database
but in different layouts I'm using addValueEventListener and addListenerForSingleValueEvent and I know that addValueEventListener should be remove after leaving the layout (in onDestroy()).
so my question is how to stop Listener from FirebaseRecyclerAdapter after i leave the layout that FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using an adapter from Firebase-UI you can stop it from listening for changes by calling `adapter.stopListening()`, typically in your activity's `onStop` method.

If you're attaching your own listeners with `addValueEventListener` or `addChildEventListener`, you indeed need to remove them once they are no longer needed. To do this you need to keep track of the listeners you added and then call [`removeEventListener` on the query or reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#removeEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener))..

So if you added a listener with:

```
ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
   ...
});
ref.addValueEventListener(listener);
```

You can then remove it (for example in `onStop`) with:

```
remove.removeEventListener(listener);
```

---

Note that listeners added with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` automatically remove themselves after they get the first value from the database, so you typically don't need to remove those in your code.

Comment: I find this solution 
Is it good solution to remove listener when leave activity

Comment: That depends on your use-case. Most use-cases should remove listeners when the activity is paused, but some shouldn't. If you don't know which one your use-case requires, you're most likely on the "most" camp and should remove the listeners.

Comment: most of my questions before I ask them I found your answers in all stackOverFlow 
really you're my super hero and I also memorize your name for long time 
Thank you so much for your helping